# prove $a^nb^{n^2+n}$ is not regular by intersection

Tags: computer-science, automata, regular-language, pumping-lemma

I want to prove that this language is not regular $L = a^nb^{n^2+n}; n \geq 0$

It proved a bit challenging to prove it directly, and thus I am looking for the intersection way.

I want a regular $L_1$ such that $L \cap L_1 = L_2$ such that $L_2$ is not regular as well, $L_2$ should be something easy to prove and we know. This way it might be simpler to prove $L$ is not regular. Could you help with this please?

For example I proved $L_3 = a^nb^{n^2}$ not regular the following way.

We have $L_3 \cap b^* = b^{n^2}$, we know that $b^*$ is regular, thus, if $L_3$ is regular, then $b^{n^2}$ is regular, but since $b^{n^2}$ is not, then, $L_3$ is not.

But I don't know how to approach $L$ in a similar way, because directly it is not easy.

Comment: $L_3 \cap b^* \not= b^{n^2}$.  For example, $b^4\not\in L_3$.

Comment: $L_3 \cap b^* = \epsilon$

Comment: $L_3\cap b^*=\{\epsilon\}$, where $\epsilon=a^0b^0=b^0$ is the empty string.

Comment: Have you learned regular languages are closed under string homomorphism?

Comment: I did indeed, why?

Comment: Map $a$ to the empty string. Then prove $b^{n^2+n}$ is not regular.

Comment: Simpler than that ? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4602308/prove-anbn2n-n-geq-0-is-regular-or-not-regular

Comment: Cross-posted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4602429/14578, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156318/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: See https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/156323/755 for a proof using string homomorphism, as well as a proof using the pumping lemma.